# Can't load random picture from folder in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JS and websites and I'm trying to make a web page which would load a random cat picture from a Cat folder (it is in the same directory as the HTML code). When I start the page, it loads the meow1.jpeg, but after I click the button it doesn't load anything. Why does it do so and how to change it? Is it a problem with directory?

My folder "Cat" contains 4 pictures right now named: "meow1.jpeg", "meow2.jpeg" and so on.

```
<img id="img" src="Cat/meow1.jpeg" alt="Random cat image">
<button onclick="show_cat()" id="button">Click</button>

<script>
    function show_cat() {
        var catNr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1; // add 1 to avoid 0 as a random number
        let catUrl = "/Cat/meow" + catNr + ".jpeg"; // specify the path to the Cat folder and concatenate the random number with the file extension
        document.getElementById("img").src = catUrl; // set the src attribute of the img element to the random image path
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The URL in the image is `Cat/`, but the JS uses `/Cat/`. Please be aware that these may not be the same place since the first is a relative path and the second is an absolute path.

Comment: The URL in the HTML is `Cat/`, but in your JS its `/Cat/`. That means if you click the button, it tries to get the image from the root folder because `/Cat/` is an absolute path and `Cat/` is relative. Learn more here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see that!